# Oracle10G: Using relational operator?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

I'm creating a table for the previously created cluster. when i try to write the code for the attribute "rate_per_unit" to be greater than 0 then finally generates the error at that line.
So how to make "rate_per_unit" should be greater than 0?

Here is what i tried to do that:

```
CREATE TABLE purchase (
  bill_no       INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
  bill_date     DATE        NOT NULL,
  customer_id   INTEGER,
  product_name  VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
  quantity      INTEGER     NOT NULL,
  rate_per_unit NUMBER(6, 2) >0,
  total_amount  NUMBER(10, 2),
  cluster       customer_cluster (customer_id)
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for the check constraint

```
create table purchase(bill_no ineger primary key,
bill_date Date not null,
customer_id integer,
product_name varchar(10) not null,
Quanity integer not null,
Rate_per_unit number(6,2),
total amount number(10,2),
cluster customer_cluster(customer_id)
);

ALTER TABLE purchase
ADD CONSTRAINT rates_check
CHECK (Rate_per_unit > 0);
```